# How to debug getResourceAsStream()?

Tags: java, apache-commons

My Java code is as follows:

```
InputStream in = getClass().getResourceAsStream("hello/say_hello.txt");
System.out.println ("InputStream = " + in + " and CWD is: " + System.getProperty("user.dir"));
IOUtils.copy(in, out);
```

I run the test from `~/work/my_project`

And the complete path for the file I am loading is `~/work/my_project/hello/say_hello.txt`

But on running the above example, I get:

```
InputStream = null and working directory is !~/work/my_project
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copyLarge(IOUtils.java:1792) ~[commons-io-2.4.jar:2.4]
    at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copyLarge(IOUtils.java:1769) ~[commons-io-2.4.jar:2.4]
    at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copy(IOUtils.java:1744) ~[commons-io-2.4.jar:2.4]
    at myproject.addTestUser(Validation.java:157) ~[classes/:na]
```

Now, my question is: How do I debug this?
How can I print the paths scanned by `getResourceAsStream()` and how can I add the current-working-directory to it?

NOTE: The above is a stripped down version of a greater code-base and it is infeasible to share the whole project here.

Comment: First and foremost; I sure hope your're calling `close` on that `InputStream`. The `getClass().getResourceAsStream()` simply scans the `ClassPath`. No debugging necessary.

Comment: Maybe the file is not available, not readable or is being used by another program.

Comment: Is that directory on your classpath?

Comment: Resources are embedded in your JAR file, or the directory structure of your compiled application. I don't understand how the current working directory is supposed to be part of it.

Comment: That directory is the current-working-directory as seen by the output of the program. I was hoping that it would be on the classpath by default, no? If no, then how do I add to the classpath?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight unless one adds the `CWD` to the `CLASSPATH`...

Comment: @user2250246 of course not! That would be a ridiculously stupid thing to do by default - for example, what if the `.jar` is _in_ the `CWD`? How are you running your program?

Comment: If you just trying to read a file why don't you use the class [Files](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html) instead?

Answer (score 2):

Because the path "hello/say_hello.txt" does not start with a "/", `Class.getResourceAsStream` will interpret its argument as a *relative* path. Relative to what? Relative to the package containing the class that's doing the loading.

So let's say you have a class `com.example.Foo` and in that class you call `getClass().getResourceAsStream("hello/say_hello.txt")`. This will attempt to load a resource called "com/example/hello/say_hello.txt". It will look for this file under any of the directories listed in the class path, or at this location inside any JAR in the class path.

How do you get the file to be inside the JAR? As @eckes mentioned, most of the popular IDEs and build tools will handle this for you if you put the file in your source tree at "src/main/resources/com/example/hello/say_hello.txt". You can [view the contents of the JAR](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/view.html) (or rename the JAR to have a file extension of ".zip" and unzip it) to make sure the file is present.

Answer (score 1):

The current work directory has nothing to do with the getResource(AsStream) functions. The later works on your classpath, it might include the start directory, but more likely the JAR only. If running in your IDE typically src/main/resources/* are on your classpath.

Answer (score 0):

Though it is not impossible, it would be a hard task to debug JRE code. I recommend you to read carefully the [public documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream(java.lang.String)) instead:

You'll see that `getResourceAsStream` search files **upon the directory/jar file were your class has been loaded from**.

And if you want a clearer form to what is the actual path it resolves to when loading resources, I'd recommend you to try instead the very similar [getResource](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource(java.lang.String)) method, to see the returned URL.

Comment: @BoristheSpider Well said. I meant it is a hard task to follow most of the JRE's old, source code.